# Determine if Dictionary Contains All of a Set of Keys

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine if a `Dictionary<string, string>` object contains *all* of a set of `string` objects as keys.

I'm probably not making any sense so here's some example code using a definite set of strings:

```
public static bool ContainsKeys(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
  return dictionary.ContainsKey("fname") && dictionary.ContainsKey("lname") && dictionary.ContainsKey("address1") &&
         dictionary.ContainsKey("city") && dictionary.ContainsKey("state") && dictionary.ContainsKey("zip");
}
```

The idea here is to accept an arbitrary set of strings as `keys` and check if the keys of the `Dictionary<string, string>` object contain all of the strings in `keys`.

I was trying to go down the LINQ road with this:

```
public static bool ContainsKeys(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string[] keys)
{
  var query = from entry in dictionary
              where keys.Contains(entry.Key)
              select entry;

  return query.Any();
}
```

I have no idea if I'm on the right path though - I think this might work if I wanted to know if `dictionary` contained any of those strings as keys.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Something like this should meet your requirement. Apply proper validations around your arguments, of course.

```
return keys.Any() 
    && keys.All(key => dictionary.ContainsKey(key));
```

Note: I include `Any` because `All` will return *true* if the source sequence (keys) is actually empty. If you don't mind this, then eliminate the use of `Any`.

Comment: For those who prefer the shortened version:

`return keys.Any() 
    && keys.All(dictionary.ContainsKey);`

Comment: @DanielS how does `keys.All(dictionary.ContainsKey)` work? Or what do I Google to understand that syntax?

Comment: @AlexKwitny "*.All()" method is expecting a predicate, which dictionary.ContainsKey method is satisfying

Answer (score 6):

This can be done pretty simply using the [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) extension method.

```
return keys.All(k => dictionary.ContainsKey(k));
```

This will check that the given predicate (`dictionary.ContainsKey(k)`) is true for all keys in the given array.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ is indeed good for this sort of thing:

```
public static bool ContainsKeys(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string[] keys)
{
  return keys.All(dictionary.ContainsKey);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, just use `Except` to eliminate the keys that are in the `Dictionary` and check if anything is left over;

```
return !keys.Except(dictionary.Keys).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14989449/403765), here is the complete source code for an extension method that will work on ANY type of Dictionary, not just one with string keys:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Collections.Generic
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static class IDictionaryExtensions
    {

        public static bool ContainsKeys<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEnumerable<TKey> keys)
        {
            return keys.Any() && keys.All(key => dictionary.ContainsKey(key));
        }

    }

}
```